# PHP Error - Uploading a file

Tags: php, iis, upload

I'm trying to write some PHP to upload a file to a folder on my webserver. Here's what I have:

```
<?php
    if ( !empty($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) ) {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], './' . $_FILES['file']['name']);
        header('Location: http://www.mywebsite.com/dump/');
        exit;
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dump Upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Upload a File</h1>
        <form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000000" />
            Select the File:<br /><input type="file" name="file" /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm getting these errors:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(./test.txt) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in E:\inetpub\vhosts\mywebsite.com\httpdocs\dump\upload.php on line 3
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\WINDOWS\Temp\phpA30E.tmp' to './test.txt' in E:\inetpub\vhosts\mywebsite.com\httpdocs\dump\upload.php on line 3
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at E:\inetpub\vhosts\mywebsite.com\httpdocs\dump\upload.php:3) in E:\inetpub\vhosts\mywebsite.com\httpdocs\dump\upload.php on line 4

PHP version 4.4.7
Running IIS on a Windows box. This particular file/folder has 777 permissions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As it's Windows, there is no real 777. If you're using [chmod](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php), check the Windows-related comments.

Check that the IIS Account can access (read, write, modify) these two folders:

```
E:\inetpub\vhosts\mywebsite.com\httpdocs\dump\
C:\WINDOWS\Temp\
```

Answer (score 17):

OMG

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], './' . $_FILES['file']['name']);
```

Don't do that. `$_FILES['file']['name']` could be `../../../../boot.ini` or any number of bad things. You should never trust this name. You should rename the file something else and associate the original name with your random name. At a minimum use `basename($_FILES['file']['name'])`.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a path.  The following code works for me:

```
<?php

if ( !empty($_FILES['file']) ) {
    $from = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $to = dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];

    if( move_uploaded_file($from, $to) ){
        echo 'Success';   
    } else {
        echo 'Failure';   
    }

    header('Location: http://www.mywebsite.com/dump/');
    exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\WINDOWS\Temp\phpA30E.tmp' to './people.xml' in E:\inetpub\vhosts\mywebsite.com\httpdocs\dump\upload.php on line 3

is the important line it says you can't put the file where you want it and this normally means a permissions problem

check the process running the app (normally the webservers process for php) has the rights to write a file there.

EDIT:

hang on a bit
I jumped the gun a little is the path to the file in the first line correct?

Answer (score 1):

Another think to observe  is your directory separator, you are using / in a Windows box..

Answer (score 1):

Add the IIS user in the 'dump' folders security persmissions group, and give it read/write access.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder named "image" with folder permission `777`

```
<?php
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"image/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

We found using below path

`{['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] + 'path to folder'`

and giving everyone full access to the folder resolved the issue.

Make sure to not reveal the location in the address bar. No sense in giving the location away.