# I can not upload a file via php

Tags: php, html, mysql, upload

I am trying to upload an image into a database via php, but I face the follow problem.

```
Upload failed
Here is some more debugging info:
Notice:  Undefined index: filetoUpload in C:\Users\Konstantina\Desktop\Upload.php on line 39
```

Upload.php code :

```
$uploaddir = 'upload/';

if(!file_exists($uploaddir)){
    if(mkdir($uploaddir,0777,true)){}else{echo "fail to create folder";}

}
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
      echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    } else {
       echo "Upload failed";
    }

    echo "</p>";
    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
    echo($_FILES['filetoUpload']['errors']);
```

Insert.html code :

```
<form action="Upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myform" id="myform">
            <label >  Select image </label>
             <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" > 

<input id="upload" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">

        </form>
```

I have turn on `file_uploads=On`

Comment: As i see you file (upload.php) is on desktop? Am i right. put it in your xampp or wampp or lamp htdocs folder to run. otherwise it will not execute.

Comment: Clue: Variables are case-sensitive. Typos are off-topic.

Comment: Plus, the file does NOT upload at all? given there's only a typo in your `echo($_FILES['filetoUpload']['errors']);` that shouldn't prevent your file from being uploaded. You're just echoing "after" your upload code.

Comment: *Ahem*, are these even being read? ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: Wherever i create the upload file, it dosen't work.

Yes it doesn't even read :/

Comment: what's your webserver type and platform?

Comment: My platform is Aptana Studio 3 and my webserver  Apache, if I understand you right

Comment: Mamp, Xampp, Wamp, other?

Comment: Ohh yeah, Xampp I forgot it.

Comment: if you made any changes to your system files and did not restart services after making a change in there, then those changes won't take effect until you do.

Comment: Yes, I know that and I have already done a restart.

Comment: are you on Windows, Mac, or Linux? Xampp runs on all of those. am thinking you're on Windows, correct?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3618/ and http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php about Windows and this Q&A on Stack http://stackoverflow.com/q/11435132/ - Further your research using "upload files php windows" for keywords as I did.

Answer (score 0):

You're outputting the wrong index to retrieve the error:

```
echo($_FILES['filetoUpload']['errors']);
```

should be:

```
echo($_FILES['fileToUpload']['errors']);
```

Afther this, we can know what the error is based on the manual:

http://php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: Thank you for your note, but it doesn't show me any further information about the errors

Comment: I suggest using `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to debug read/write error that may occur. `$_FILES['fileToUpload']['errors']` will show upload error like file size, no file selection or unwritable temp dir, but will not show errors on move_uploaded_file.

Comment: It shows me,  22527 error, but I didn't find any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

i think you use full path of upload directory

```
$uploaddir = 'upload/';
```

use like

```
 $uploaddir = '/var/www/upload/';
```

also you have

```
    echo "</p>";
    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
    echo($_FILES['filetoUpload']['errors']); // here to is small t while in other you have To
```